# Google Form permit to open at certain times everyday

Tags: google-apps-script

Im looking for a script that permit to open a google form everday from 9 AM to 3 PM. After 3 PM it should restrict to open it.

Thanks

Comment: its always 9 am somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function that creates a trigger. Something like:

```
function triggerClose() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('closeForm')
    .timeBased()
    .everyDays(1)
    .atHour(3)
    .forForm(FormApp.openById(FORM_ID))
    .create();
}
```

You can use the documentation at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder to refine this code. Use a similar structure to build a trigger that opens the form at 9 am.

This calls a function every day at hour 3. Here are a couple examples of open and close form functions:

```
function closeForm() {
  FormApp.openById(FORM_ID).setAcceptingResponses(false);
}

function openForm() {
  FormApp.openById(FORM_ID).setAcceptingResponses(true);
}
```

I hope this is helpful.